# How to prove this version of the fundamental theorem of calculus for curves in the closure of a domain

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, curves

**Dear Downvoters: if you leave a comment, you can influence the way this post gets modified, if you don't this post might never satisfy you - even though I keep editing**

---

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ denote a bounded domain (open and connected) and consider a vector field $g = (g_1,\dots,g_n) \in C^\infty(\overline\Omega)^n$.

Here $C^\infty(\overline\Omega)$ denotes the set of all restrictions of vector fields $u|_{\overline\Omega}$ of functions $u \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $$\sup_{|\alpha| < \infty, x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |D^\alpha u | < \infty.$$
On this space we define the norm
$$
\| u\| := \sup_{|\alpha| \leq k, x \in \overline \Omega} |D^\alpha u(x)|.
$$
Considering the product space $C^\infty(\overline\Omega)^n$, on this space we define the norm for a vector field $g$ as
$$
\| g\| := \sup_{j = 1,\dots,n} \| g_j \|
$$

These definitions are taken from **Sohr - The Navier-Stokes Equations: An Elementary Functional Analytic Approach**.

One version of the FTC for closed curves I am familiar with, works with closed curves and domains, not the closure of domains. However there seems to be a modification of this theorem that I am not able to prove:

> If for each closed piecewise $C^1$ curve $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to \overline\Omega$ the curve integral
>   $$
> \int_0^1 g(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) dt = 0,
> $$
>   then $g$ has the form $g = \nabla U$ with $U \in C^\infty(\overline\Omega)$.

---

- Do you maybe know how to prove this from the original theorem?
- Can you recommend a reference where I could look the proof of this particular theorem up?

This "theorem" is again referenced in **Sohr - The Navier-Stokes Equations: An Elementary Functional Analytic Approach, p.74**

---

**EDIT to avoid further confusion:**

I know that if for each closed curve the integral vanishes we can define a candidate for a potential function
$$
f(x) := \int_p^x g \cdot ds
$$
independent of the curve chosen to connect an arbitrary but fixed point $p$ and the point $x$.

I know a proof that does it just like this, but only for domains. When it comes to prove that $f$ is indeed differentiable at $x$ the fact that a domain is open is used.

What I need is some extension property that guarantees me the differentiability in an open neighborhood of boundary points $x \in \partial \Omega$.

Comment: Do you assume that $\gamma (0) = \gamma(1)$?

Comment: @ArcticChar: Yes. I have corrected my post.

Comment: @Thomas: This is what the original proof of the FTC for closed curves does. But the proof (at least the one I am familiar with) is only formulated for domains, not for the closure of a domain.

Comment: If the integral of a form vanishes on any closed curve, the form is exact. This is because the hypothesis implies that integrals are path independent, so you can define $U(P)=\int_{P_0}^P gds$ where the path between $P_0$ and $P$ can be chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: @XipanXiao This is was Thomas already said... but he deleted his comment. Defining $U(P)$ in this way is what the original proof of the FTC for closed curves does. But the proof (at least the one I am familiar with) is only formulated for domains, not for the closure of a domain.

Comment: Such a properties (the connection between closedness and exactness of differential forms) heavily depend on the topology of the domain $\Omega$, which has to be a surface (in the broader sense; a manifold). And the structure of the boundary $\partial\Omega$ itself plays a role too: it also has to be piecewise smooth to some degree.

Comment: General idea here is that the potential $U(x)$ is defined as $\int_{x_0}^x \mathbf g \cdot d\mathbf s$ by any smooth enough path connecting the point $x$ and some base point $x_0$.

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky: What is the intention of your comments? I have already pointed out, that I am aware of the general idea (in the comments and by an edit of my post) , but I don't know how to extend the proof to the closure of the domain. You say I need more regularity of the boundary of my domain? Can you cite a reference with a proof for the same or a similar statement that uses domains with e.g. Lipschitz-boundaries?

Comment: @el_tenedor The point was to mention some general theory which might come handy for you. Is this a problem?

Comment: @el_tenedor Well, Ok, I wasn't original. Anyway, what exactly don't you understand about the regularity conditions on the boundary? The differential (of the vector field) on the boundary is not the same thing as on the interior (the dimension is less by one). So the boundary itself is a manifold and you just apply the same reasoning to it. (That's also why I cited the notion of a surface as relevant.)

Comment: @el_tenedor Finally, what you really need is the notion of *directional* derivative (and also limit and continuity).

Answer (score -1):

Suppose the circulation of the vector field on any closed path is zero.
Then the integral on any path depends only on the starting and ending point, but not on the path itself.
Fix a point in the domain and consider the integral on a path, going from the point, as a function of the other end; it's well-defined function.

To check that this function is indeed the potential of the vector field, one might consider a path consisting solely from linear pieces, going along the coordinate axes.

P.S. Of course, it means that each connected part of the domain has it's own potential, and the potential itself is, precisely speaking, not just a function, but a class of them (element of a factor space) given by this particular function.

P.P.S. And of course on the boundary points you have to use the derivative by a vector:
$\lim_{h\to 0} h^{-1}(f(\mathbf x +h\mathbf v)-f(\mathbf x))$, where $h: \mathbb R_{>0}$ and $\mathbf v$ gives the direction.